# A way to rotate plot in R

Tags: r, plot, rotation

Rotate a plot (with below rotation setting) seems to be impossible in R according to Google.

So I am looking for a way to do that, but still no success till now.

Rotation setting :

- The rotation center is the origin of plot ({0,0})
- The given angle will be the angle between the y axis and the plot.

Here is a code where

- `a` is something depending on angle and x axis length. (I think)
- `b` is something depending on angle and y axis length. (I think)

:

```
speed <- cars$speed
dist <- cars$dist
plot(speed,dist, xlim=c(0,121), ylim=c(0,121))


xTemp <- speed
speed <- speed + (a)
dist <- dist + (b)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(speed,dist, xlim=c(0,121), ylim=c(0,121), col="red")
```

Any idea of `a` and `b` values ?

Here is for example a code in wich the plot is rotated by *about 50* degrees from the  y axis (Notice that is is not a true rotation. `speed` value is extended after rotation.. I don't now how to fix it.) :

```
speed <- cars$speed
dist <- cars$dist
plot(speed,dist, xlim=c(0,121), ylim=c(0,121))


xTemp <- speed
speed <- speed + dist
dist <- dist - xTemp

par(new=TRUE)
plot(speed,dist, xlim=c(0,121), ylim=c(0,121), col="red")
```

[image: It gives :]

Comment: Do you want to rotate the whole plot, including the axes, or just the points that are plotted?

Comment: Only the plot. Not the axes

Comment: This is unclear. Can you make a picture of what you want to do?

Answer (score 10):

Just apply a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) 
to your data.

```
angle <- pi/3
M <- matrix( c(cos(angle), -sin(angle), sin(angle), cos(angle)), 2, 2 )
plot( as.matrix(cars[,c("speed","dist")]) %*% M )
```

What happens may be clearer on a different example:

```
library(mlbench)
d <- mlbench.smiley()$x
op <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(d, asp=1)
plot(as.matrix(d) %*% M, col="red", asp=1)
par(op)
```

[image: Rotation]

Comment: Thank you but it is not really what I want to do. I edited my question.

Comment: It is actually the same thing: 
your example is a rotation of angle -pi/4 (45 degrees)
followed by a multiplication by `sqrt(2)`.
I have added an example that makes this clearer.

Comment: The problem of your example is that the rotation center is not the origin of the plot which is {0,0}. What I want is to turn my plot around its origin.

Comment: The center of the rotation is the origin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks I found the solution :

```
speed <- cars$speed
dist <- cars$dist
angle <- 45
plot(speed,dist, xlim=c(-121,121), ylim=c(-121,121))
speed1 <- double(); dist1=double()
for(i in 1:length(speed)){
    sq <- sqrt((speed[i]*speed[i]) + (dist[i]*dist[i]))
    angleInit <- (180*atan(dist[i]/speed[i]))/pi
    angle2 <- angleInit - angle
    speed1[i] <- cos(pi*angle2/180) * sq
    dist1[i]  <- sin(pi*angle2/180) * sq
}
par(new=TRUE)
plot(speed1,dist1, xlim=c(-121,121), ylim=c(-121,121), col="red")
```

Thank you